# how to prevent recreating component tree from react error boundary

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am using Error boundary with react-query.
And when an error occurs while using useMutation in react-query, I want to handle it through error boundary, but the component recreating.

At this time, I don't want the value contained in the state to fly away, and I don't want to use state management. because I think it's unnecessary.

And some api using useQuery leave a log through error boundaries. But I want the screen to remain the same.

Is there any good way to prevent it?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand the question. What does "but the component recreating" mean please? Error Boundaries will always unmount the component tree and mount the Error Boundary instead, that's the nature of Error Boundaries. It also means that all state in the tree below is gone. If you want "the screen to remain the same", I don't think you can use error boundaries ...

Comment: @TkDodo
Sorry, my English is not good.
I meant that through the ErrorBoundary, the following message appears on the console and is always recreated.

"React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, ErrorBoundary."

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.